# Getting all the pages at once using PDF.js

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, pdf.js

I'm developing PDFViewer using PDF.js in Angular 5. I'm facing problem while displaying the Pdf all pages at time.

**Problem Description**:
First page is coming normal but remaining pages are coming side by side.

**Screenshots of the problem**:[image][image]

I'm trying to figure out that where I'm doing wrong. Any suggestion?
Thanks in Advance!!

Here is my code:

```js
PDFJS.getDocument(src1).then((_pdfDoc) => {
        this.pdf = _pdfDoc;
        this.totalPages = this.pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
        let viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
        for(let page = 1; page <= this.totalPages; page++) {
                let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    
                canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas';      
                viewer.appendChild(canvas);    
                this.renderPage(page, canvas);
         }
});
renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
    this.pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
      let viewport = page.getViewport(1);
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;          
      page.render({canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport: viewport});
});
}
```

```html
<div id ="viewer" class="pdfViewer"> </div>
```

**UPDATED QUESTION**:

- The Problem (i.e., pages coming side by side) has been fixed by
  adding additional div tag in the page. Have a look at my code

```js
PDFJS.getDocument(src1).then((_pdfDoc) => {
        this.pdf = _pdfDoc;
        this.totalPages = this.pdf.pdfInfo.numPages;
        let viewer = document.getElementById('viewer');
            for(let page = 1; page <= this.totalPages; page++)
            {
                        let childViewer=document.createElement("div");
                        childViewer.className='childviewer';
                        childViewer.align="center";
                        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");    
                        canvas.className = 'pdf-page-canvas'; 
                        childViewer.appendChild(canvas);
                        viewer.appendChild(childViewer);    
                        this.renderPage(page, canvas);
            }
  });
 renderPage(pageNumber, canvas) {
        this.pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function(page) {
          let viewport = page.getViewport(1);
          canvas.height = viewport.height;
          canvas.width = viewport.width;              
          page.render({canvasContext: canvas.getContext('2d'), viewport:    viewport});
    });
    
 }
```

```html
<div id ="viewer"  align="center" class="pdfViewer2">        
</div>
```

- But I'm facing new issue i.e., First page is not aligned with rest of the pages.There is a small position mismatch between first page and remaining pages and rest of the pages are coming perfectly.
  Please have a look here.
  . [image]

Comment: Are the pages side by side one `<canvas>` or two?

Comment: Hi @BenWest,Sorry, I didn't get your question properly. The two <canvas> elements are coming side by side. That is what my problem is. It is like 1st <canvas> element then below that two <canvas> elements and below that next two <canvas> elements and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS all looks fine, so the layout probably comes from CSS. `.pdf-page-canvas { display: block }` should do it.

Comment: Hi @BenWest, I tried this CSS code as well. But it didn't solve the problem. when I minimize the window it is working but if I maximize the window then again it is the same issue.

Comment: @RaviKumarB What CSS styles are applied to the `<canvas>`es?

Comment: hi @BenWest, Please have look into Updated question. I'm facing new issue.

Comment: @RaviKumarB Still need to see your CSS. If there were no styles applied to your `<canvas>` elements, they would stack like you want them to - so there must be styles which make them lay out differently.